Godot4.3 NavigationServer2D get path based on obstacles
I just want to define obstacles and then get the desired path, but my simple code does not seem to work. It keeps printing an empty path [] every frame.
extends Node2D

var map: RID
var region: RID
var poly = NavigationPolygon.new()
var geometry = NavigationMeshSourceGeometryData2D.new()
    
func _ready():
    # Use call deferred to make sure the entire scene tree nodes are setup
    # else await on 'physics_frame' in a _ready() might get stuck.
    call_deferred("custom_setup")

func custom_setup():
    # Create a new navigation map.
    map = NavigationServer2D.map_create()
    NavigationServer2D.map_set_active(map, true)

    # Create a new navigation region and add it to the map.
    region = NavigationServer2D.region_create()
    NavigationServer2D.region_set_map(region, map)
    NavigationServer2D.region_set_enabled(region, true)
    
    # Create a procedural navigation mesh for the region.
    poly.cell_size = NavigationServer2D.map_get_cell_size(map)
    geometry.add_obstruction_outline(PackedVector2Array([
        Vector2(15, 20), Vector2(50, 20), Vector2(50,30), Vector2(15, 30)
    ]))
    geometry.add_traversable_outline(PackedVector2Array([
        Vector2(0, 0), Vector2(0, 50), Vector2(50, 50), Vector2(50, 0)
    ]))
    NavigationServer2D.bake_from_source_geometry_data(poly, geometry, on_geo_baked)

func on_geo_baked():
    NavigationServer2D.region_set_navigation_polygon(region, poly)

func _physics_process(delta: float) -> void:
    var start_position: Vector2 = Vector2(10, 10)
    var target_position: Vector2 = Vector2(40, 40)
    var optimize_path: bool = false

    var path: PackedVector2Array = NavigationServer2D.map_get_path(
        map,
        start_position,
        target_position,
        optimize_path
    )

    print("Found a path!")
    print(path)


After some tiresome try and error, this is the code that i found to be working:
extends Node2D

var map: RID
var region: RID
var poly = NavigationPolygon.new()
var geometry = NavigationMeshSourceGeometryData2D.new()
    
func _ready():
    # Use call deferred to make sure the entire scene tree nodes are setup
    # else await on 'physics_frame' in a _ready() might get stuck.
    call_deferred("custom_setup")

func custom_setup():
    # Create a new navigation map.
    map = NavigationServer2D.map_create()
    NavigationServer2D.map_set_active(map, true)

    # Create a new navigation region and add it to the map.
    region = NavigationServer2D.region_create()
    NavigationServer2D.region_set_map(region, map)
    NavigationServer2D.region_set_enabled(region, true)
    poly.agent_radius = 1
    
    # Create a procedural navigation mesh for the region.
    poly.cell_size = NavigationServer2D.map_get_cell_size(map)
    geometry.append_obstruction_outlines([
        PackedVector2Array([
            Vector2(0, 20), Vector2(20, 20), Vector2(20,30), Vector2(0, 30)
        ]),
        PackedVector2Array([
            Vector2(35, 20), Vector2(50, 20), Vector2(50,30), Vector2(35, 30)
        ]),
    ])
    geometry.add_traversable_outline(PackedVector2Array([
        Vector2(0, 0), Vector2(0, 50), Vector2(50, 50), Vector2(50, 0)
    ]))
    NavigationServer2D.region_set_navigation_polygon(region, poly)
    NavigationServer2D.bake_from_source_geometry_data(poly, geometry, on_geo_baked)

func on_geo_baked():
    NavigationServer2D.region_set_navigation_polygon(region, poly)

func _physics_process(delta: float) -> void:
    var start_position: Vector2 = Vector2(5, 5)
    var target_position: Vector2 = Vector2(45, 45)
    var optimize_path: bool = true

    var path: PackedVector2Array = NavigationServer2D.map_get_path(
        map,
        start_position,
        target_position,
        optimize_path
    )

    print("Found a path!")
    print(path)

